# Are all headers in /usr/include considered to be Public API on the MAS?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, mac-app-store

Are all headers in /usr/include guaranteed to be considered part of the Public APIs when it comes to Mac App Store submissions?

Consider for example the file /usr/include/copyfile.h

The comments in this file say this: "This implementation is incomplete and the interface may change in a future release." Does this render the header non-public? How do I determine if a header is considered public?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the bottom section of [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/OSX_Technology_Overview/SystemFrameworks/SystemFrameworks.html) documentation page.

Excerpt:

> Mac OS X includes many dynamic libraries in the /usr/lib directory and its subdirectories. Dynamic shared libraries are identified by their .dylib extension. Header files for the libraries are located in /usr/include.

It seems like the implication here is that the `.dylib` libraries included with OS X are fair game for use in your application, but you need to be aware that they don't guarantee to have a particular version of the lib on e.g. Lion, so you should include the most generic version you can.

As @Dan said, the other thing which would tip you off to a library being OK to use would be if it has a manpage. [copyfile](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/copyfile.3.html) has a man page, so it's fine to use (since they're showing you how to use it!). To make things even fuzzier, check out the [getattrlist](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/getattrlist.2.html) man page, and search for 'copyfile'. One of the flags you can read for volume capabilities indicates support for a *second* copyfile() API. So in this case there are 2 copyfile() APIs and you're only allowed to use the one with a manpage, as the other one is marked here as being private and undocumented.

Any headers not contained in a Framework folder and not matched with a `.dylib` or a manpage, I would generally avoid using.

Answer (score 5):

It's public if it's documented. You've got LOTS of .h files on your system that refer to private APIs. That's not how you know whether it's store-safe. It's store-safe it it's documented in the framework documentation.

Comment: Do you have time to look for copyfile in the Xcode documentation? You will see it there. It says "The copyfile() API was introduced in Mac OS X 10.5". Does this mean that using the /usr/include/copyfile.h header is guaranteed to be MAS-safe?